# Remove or copy a file all at once

Tags: command-line, terminal, directory

Suppose I have 4 directories :

```
Directory_1 Directory_2 Directory_3 Directory_4
```

1. Is there a command line in a terminal Linux I can use to **copy** a file to all of these directories?
2. Is there a command line in a terminal Linux I can use to **remove** a file to all of these directories in the same time?

Comment: Remove what, exactly? All files from the directories, all files with a particular name from the directories? Including or excluding subdirectories? What's your actual use case? Are you familiar with the common utilities for copying and removing files and how they're used? Do you have something you've already tried, or are you just looking for a ready answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a command line in a terminal Linux I can use to copy a file to all of these directories?

Yes, but it's not something obvious to a beginner

```
tee Directory_{1..4}/file <file >/dev/null
```

Another approach is to use four separate commands

```
cp file Directory_1
cp file Directory_2
cp file Directory_3
cp file Directory_4
```

or with a shell such as `bash` that understands the `{1..4}` expression, a loop covering all four directories

```
for d in Directory_{1..4}; do cp file "$d"; done
```

> Is there a command line in a terminal Linux I can use to remove a file to all of these directories in the same time?

Yes. `rm` with a wildcard

```
rm Directory_*/file
```

Comment: `tee Directory_{1..4}/file <file >/dev/null`

Comment: @Kusalananda I always forget that `tee` can be (mis)used like this. Thank you